# Open a page in Iframe from code behind in Asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, iframe

How can I execute the following code as a JavaScript from the code behind file (against a button click).

```
<a class="iframe2 cboxElement" href='<%# ResolveUrl("Project_MainPageEdit.aspx?editpid=1778" ) %>'>Project Details (edit)</a>
```

What I'm trying to do is, I am trying to open up Project_MainPageEdit.aspx as an IFrame using the above code. It is working perfectly fine in a different aspx page, but does not work in this Page. When click on 'Project Details' link, Iframe opens up, but nothing shows up. What is the reason?

I'm thinking if I call the above code from code behind using JavaScript it might work?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a function from code-behind using Javascript, unless you are using node.js, which is obviously not the case here. Also, the structure you are using is not an `iframe`, it is an anchor. If you mean that it is inside an `iframe`, then you should check whether the page exists, the path you are referring to is correct and whether you get any exceptions/errors. You should debug your code, but check the url as well. If you open your browser console and inspect the given element, is its `href` corresponding to the expected one?